# React hooks useEffect calls mutiple times when redux store other data changed

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, react-hooks, use-effect

my code like this:

Info component:

```
import {
 getAttachData,
} from '@src/actions/creators/account'
 
const Info: React.FC = () => {
  const info = useSelector<any, Account>(state => state.getIn(['account', 'info']).toJS())
  const list = useSelector<any, Data[]>(state => state.getIn(['account', 'list']).toJS())
  const attach = useSelector<any, AttachData[]>(state => state.getIn(['account', 'attach']).toJS())
  ...
  
  const handleChange = ({ select }) => {
    dispatch(getAttachData({v: select}))
  }
  
  const Template = (params) => {
    return (
     <div>
       <BaseSelect onChange={(val) => handleChange(val)} list={list} />}
     </div>
    )
  }
  
  return (
    ...
    <Template data={info} />
    {attach.map((child, cidx) => (<Template data={child} />))}
  )
}

export default Info
```

BaseSelect component:

```
const BaseSelect: React.FC<Props> = props => {
  const [selectId, setSelectId] = useState('')
  const { list } = props
  
  useEffect(() => {
    if (!isEmpty(list)) {
      ...
    }
    console.log('init')
  }, [])

  const handleChange = (value) => {
    setSelectId(value)
    
    props.onChange({
      select: value,
    })
  }
 
  return (
    <Select
      data={list}
      value={selectId}
      onChange={handleChange}
    />
  )
}

export default BaseSelect
```

when excute handleChange event in BaseSelect component, the props.onChange function will call handleChange event in info component, and dispatch http request getAttachData which will change attach data in redux store, but useEffect in BaseSelect component will also excute and in console will print 'init' two times.

console:

[image]

Comment: The effect in your question depends on list but it's not added as such and makes list a [stale closure](https://dmitripavlutin.com/react-hooks-stale-closures/). Does it help if you define the Template function outside the Info function? I bet it won't re mount but probably will have the stale closure problem. Without a reproducible example there is little we can do though.

Answer (score 0):

It's because your `Template` component re-creates every time when redux store is changing.

Just move `Template` component outside the `Info` component.

Comment: There will still be a stale closure of list in the effect callback, it does prevent Template from mounting every time but probably won't display the correct information.

Comment: You may use `useSelector` inside the `Template` component to subscribe it to actual info. You don't need use closure for this. :)